# VSCode Intellisense does not show any suggestion

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

Hello when i use VSCode for javascript sometimes intellisense doesn't show any suggestion.
It's same for other functions like for example .map, .filter vs..
Why is that ? I'am new on VSCode. Thanks to everybody for help

[Here it doesn't suggest me indexOf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/046z0.png)

[Here it recognized indexOf and show me explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBXIX.png)

Comment: Please post your code, not a screenshot of it

Comment: im taking course from udemy. Code is same with teacher but his editor suggest ondexOf() after write .in. How it's can be possible ? Is there any extension for this ? There is different thing in teacher's editor for example when he write .in suggestion show indexOf()    %27

Answer (score 0):

Its because how you're declaring your variable. VSCode doesn't know what kind of variable its going to be because you haven't defined it a default value.

Assign your variable as `let yourVar = [];`.